# What does "rerun in upstream in pipeline"?

Tags: pipeline, azure-data-factory, u-sql

I am defining a pipeline in data factory, I had some errors that I correct.
The first activity is calling an usql script to do some aggregation, I changed the script plenty of time but the error is still:

> [{"errorId":"E_CSC_USER_SYNTAXERROR","severity":"Error","component":"CSC","source":"USER","message":"syntax
>   error. Final statement did not end with a semicolon","details":"at
>   token 'usql', line 4\r\nnear the ###:\r\n**************\r\nCLARE
>   @lineitemsfile string =
>   \"/datalakerepo/input/2016/01/01lineitems.txt\";\nDECLARE @ordersfile
>   string = \"/datalakerepo/input/2016/01/01orders.txt\";\nsales.usql ###
>   \n","description":"Invalid syntax found in the
>   script.","resolution":"Correct the script syntax, using expected
>   token(s) as a
>   guide.","helpLink":"","filePath":"","lineNumber":4,"startOffset":228,"endOffset":232}].

seem like not all usql script is read from the data factory, so I though that may be the "rerun in upstream in pipeline" have something to do with this, like clear cache from previous script.

Anyone knows what "rerun in upstream in pipeline" does?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Rerun with upstream in pipeline" basically means "recalculate with all dependencies". For example, if one has `pipeline1 -> dataset1 -> pipeline2` and tries to rerun `pipeline2` with dependecies, then `pipeline1` and `pipeline2` will be both executed. I believe it works same with several chained activities within single pipeline.